# как получать значение при нажатии на button js

Tags: javascript

Eсть такой код:

```html
<div class="lang">
    <button value="en" id="lang-en">EN</button>
    <button value="ru" id="lang-ru">RU</button>
 </div>
```

Вопрос: Как при нажатии на соответствующую кнопку получить ее значение (value) используя нативный JS? Как правильно записать такую операцию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getValue(btn) {
  console.log(btn.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="lang">
    <button value="en" id="lang-en" onclick="getValue(this)">EN</button>
    <button value="ru" id="lang-ru" onclick="getValue(this)">RU</button>
 </div>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.lang button').forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', getValue));

function getValue(e) {
  console.log(this.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="lang">
    <button value="en" id="lang-en">EN</button>
    <button value="ru" id="lang-ru">RU</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, Игорь!

Comment: А как в этой истории присвоить значение (this.value) новой переменной, чтобы ее (переменную) можно было использовать в другой функции?

Comment: @Cobra777 "чтобы ее (переменную) можно было использовать в другой функции" - приведите пример.

Comment: Есть вторая функция,  в которую хочу засунуть значение первой функции, а именно в переменную hash

function createContent() {
  let unit;
  if (hash == 'en') {
  unit = unitArr.en;
  } else {
  unit = unitArr.ru;
  }
  unit.forEach((el) => {
    ...
  }
}

Comment: @Cobra777 Как/где вызывается `createContent`?

Comment: Хороший вопрос)) - третьей кнопкой. Забыл написать.

Comment: @Cobra777 Задайте, пожалуйста, новый вопрос.

Comment: Как-то так - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1293536/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8