# Как присвоить значение новой переменной для использования в другой функции?

Tags: javascript

Как присвоить значение новой переменной для использования в другой функции?

```js
// отрывок
document.querySelectorAll('.lang button').forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', getValue));

document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', createContent, { once: true });

function getValue(e) {
  // console.log(this.value);
  // это значение this.value передать в переменную hash для createContent()   
}

function createContent() {
  let hash = ''; // вот сюда!
  console.log(hash);
    // let unit;
    // if (hash == 'en') {
    //  unit = unitArr.en;
    // } else {
    //  unit = unitArr.ru;
    // }
  // unit.forEach((el) => {
  //  ...
  // }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>

<div class="lang">
  <button value="en" id="lang-en">EN</button>
  <button value="ru" id="lang-ru">RU</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.lang button').forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', getValue));

document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
  createContent((document.querySelector('.lang button.active') || {}).value); 
});

function getValue(e) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.lang button.active').forEach(b => b.classList.remove('active'));
  this.classList.add('active');
  console.log("getValue -", this.value);
}

function createContent(language) {
  let hash = language; // вот сюда!
  console.log("createContent -", hash);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>

<div class="lang">
  <button value="en" id="lang-en">EN</button>
  <button value="ru" id="lang-ru">RU</button>
</div>
```

> при нажатии EN или RU меняется значение "createContent -"

Оно так не работает.

```
function getValue(e) {
  ...
 
  createContent(this.value);
}
```

Comment: Идея немного другая (видимо я некорректно написал) - после клика на кнопке Click Me, при нажатии EN или RU меняется значение "createContent -", кнопку Click Me снова нажимать не надо. Значение конопок EN и RU автоматом (через переменную hash) попадают в функцию createContent()

Comment: @Cobra777 Оно так не работает.

Comment: Печально. У меня есть еще одна зацепка - hash в URL. При нажатии кнопок RU или EN динамичеcки меняется hash в URL, например: http://localhost/#ru или  http://localhost/#en. Может как-то за это можно привязаться?

Comment: @Cobra777 Мне кажется, что Вы не понимаете, что Вы спрашиваете. Сколько раз вызывается/выполняется функция `createContent`?

Comment: createContent вызывается один раз. Ее задача в проекте открыть секцию с контентом и отрисовать его. А кнопки RU и EN они отвечают только за перевод - берут из обьекта unitArr данные и подставляют в нужные теги.

Comment: По сути подобная тема уже поднималась 4 года назад - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542767/%d0%9c%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-javascript-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0 . У меня код сложился уже (если раскомментировать мой первый код).  Если я ручками ставлю в функцию createContent() в переменную let hash = 'ru'; или let hash = 'en'; у меня все чудесно рендерит на странице. Мне нужно протащить в эту функцию тек.значение RU или EN

Comment: @Cobra777 `let hash = (document.querySelector('.lang button.active') || {}).value;`

Comment: В любом случаи, спасибо Вам большое, Игорь, за идеи. Буду думать дальше как быть.

Answer (score 1):

Функции в JS имеют объектный тип, и (как любые другие объекты) могут иметь свойства.
Если функция объявлена локально - то вполне нормально использовать данную возможность языка, и обращаться с ней как к объектной переменной (но явно не стоит делать так с "чужими"/общими функциями... и нужно быть осторожным, чтобы случайно не перезаписать стандартное свойство!):

```js
const createContent = () => {
  console.log(createContent.lang);
  // ...
};
const testBtn = document.querySelector('#btn');

document.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if (evt.target.matches('.lang button')) {
    createContent.lang = evt.target.dataset.value;
    testBtn.disabled = false;
  }
});
testBtn.addEventListener('click', createContent, { once: true });
```

```html
<button id="btn" disabled>Click Me</button>
<div class="lang">
  <button data-value="en" id="lang-en">EN</button>
  <button data-value="ru" id="lang-ru">RU</button>
</div>
```

---

Хотя, конечно, более распространена практика использования обычного объекта для хранения состояния. Нужно всего лишь обеспечить доступность этого объекта для всех использующих его функций - объявив в лексическом окружении "выше" их всех... либо (самый простой вариант) добавив объект состояния свойством `window`/`global` и назвав достаточно изощренно, чтобы избежать возможного конфликта имен:

```js
window._myAwesomeAppState = {};
const createContent = () => {
  console.log(window._myAwesomeAppState.lang);
  // ...
};
const testBtn = document.querySelector('#btn');

document.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if (evt.target.matches('.lang button')) {
    window._myAwesomeAppState.lang = evt.target.dataset.value;
    testBtn.disabled = false;
  }
});
testBtn.addEventListener('click', createContent, { once: true });
```

```html
<button id="btn" disabled>Click Me</button>
<div class="lang">
  <button data-value="en" id="lang-en">EN</button>
  <button data-value="ru" id="lang-ru">RU</button>
</div>
```